# Merging two matrices in a specific sequence

Tags: r, matrix, sequence

I have a matrix **A** of order **150*24** and a second matrix **B** of order **50*24**. I want to merge the matrix **B** in matrix **A** in such a way that row of matrix **B** are

```
[1,2,3,4,5,...,50]
```

merge in **A** in such a manner that the position of the rows of matrix **B** in matrix **A** become

```
[5,6,12,13,19,20,26,27,33,34,40,41,47,48,54,55,61,62,68,69,75,76,82,83,...]
```

so the matrix **A** become of order **200*24**, how could I do this in R?

Comment: Do you want to replace the rows of A or add the rows of B in A?

Comment: I want to add the rows of B in A in such a way that the first and second rows of B become the 5th and 6th rows of A respectively and the 5th  and 6th rows of A become the 7th and 8th  rows of A, in this way we merge the rows B in the specific sequence.

Comment: Okay. see my edit

Comment: @Mael thanks for your cooperation when I run your suggested code I got the matrix after merging B is of order 192*24 which will be of order 200*24.

Comment: also, the sequence s also produce the 42 values which will be 50 because I merge B in A having 50 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the index vector and a zero matrix with the desired dimensions, then fill the matrix, like so:

```r
i <- 5:6 + rep(7L * 0:(nrow(B)/2-1), each = 2L)
R <- matrix(0, nrow(A) + nrow(B), ncol(A))
R[i, ] <- B
R[-i, ] <- A
```